# Sum over partition between current row and number from another number

Tags: sql

I need a moving sum that starts from the current row until X following rows. The problem is that X is not static (i.e. it comes from another column).

The code:

```
sum(column 0) OVER(
  ORDER BY column 1, column 2, column 3 
  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND column 4 FOLLOWING
) as X
```

column 4 is already an integer, but the SQL "complains" asking for a hard coded integer. Casting and converting didn't work either.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually SQL engines cannot handle "variables" on some parts of the SQL statement.

This is one of those cases. Unfortunately, a non-literal is not accepted at this place. You'll need to rephrase your query using a different strategy.